# Step regression with AIC criteria Python

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I am doing step regression in Python using AIC criteria. I want to recognise function y = 2+3sinx+lnx with base functions as {1,x,x^2,...,cosx,sinx}. I've finished programm, but it's not working too good, can anyone tell me why?

```
n = 500
x = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=10, size=n)
x1 = np.sort(x)
e = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, n)
y = 2+3*np.sin(x1)+np.log(x1) #noise
y2 = y +e


basic_func = {'1': x1/x1,
              'x': x1,
              'x^2': x1**2,
              'x^3': x1**3,
              'x^4': x1**4,
              'sinx': np.sin(x1),
              'cosx': np.cos(x1),
              'tanx': np.tan(x1),
              'logx': np.log(x1)}
X = pd.DataFrame(basic_func,columns=['1','x', 'x^2', 'x^3', 'x^4', 'sinx', 'cosx', 'tanx', 'logx'])
X2 = X

k = len(X2.columns)
lr = LinearRegression()

while 1:
    aic = []
    if len(X2.columns) > 2:
        for i in range(k):
            lr.fit(X2.drop(X2.columns[i],axis=1).iloc[:], y2)
            y1 = lr.predict(X2.drop(X2.columns[i],axis=1).iloc[:])
            aic.append(n*np.log(1/n*np.sum((y2-y1)**2)) + 2 * (k-1))
    else:
        for i in range(k):
            lr.fit(X2.drop(X2.columns[i], axis=1).iloc[:].values.reshape(-1, 1), y2)
            y1 = lr.predict(X2.drop(X2.columns[i], axis=1).iloc[:].values.reshape(-1, 1))
            aic.append(n * np.log(1 / n * np.sum((y2 - y1) ** 2)) + 2 * (k-1))

  lr.fit(X2.iloc[:], y2)
    y3 = lr.predict(X2.iloc[:])
    aic.append(n * np.log(1 / n * np.sum((y2 - y3) ** 2)) + 2 * k)
    aic_min = min(aic)
    r = aic.index(aic_min)

    if aic[-1] == min(aic):
        break

    k = k-1
    X2 = X2.drop(X2.columns[r],axis=1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please elaborate on "but it's not working too good". What does that mean? Don't let the users guess what your problem looks like. Is there an error message (if so, please add it to your question), is the ouput not as intended (if so, describe the mismatch), ...

Comment: You're right. So the thing is that 9 out of 10 times it gives back about 5 funcitons, usually x, x^2, x^3, x^4 and sinx or tanx. But the proper answer (sinx, logx) rarely happens.